# How to adjust the width of <code> tag within a background?

Tags: html, css

does anybody know how I can adjust the width of the text within a (code) tag so that it will always fit within the background? I am trying to let the text within the (pre) resize with the pre as the background resizes with the browser.

Pictures for reference:

[Before minimize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxyZx.png)

[After minimize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3zD7.png)

This is the current code I have.

HTML

```
<pre>
            <code>
if (condition) { statement_1_runs_if_condition_is_true;
statement_2_runs_if_condition_is_true; } else {
statement_3_runs_if_condition_is_false;
statement_4_runs_if_condition_is_false; }
            </code>
</pre>
```

CSS

```
pre {
background-color: #CCC5B9;
border: 1px solid #999;
border-radius: 3px;
display: block;
width: 60%;
margin: 0 0 0 30px;}

code{
color: #252422;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Consolas;}
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you add a sandbox so i can try to do some things and it will help not only me but for other people to help you to solve your problem :)

Comment: I am assuming you don't want the code to start throwing newlines in order to fit (since that might affect the code e.g. if a user copies it to paste elsewhere). Is that right?

Comment: @xAtifx How do i add a sand box?

Comment: sandbox is like a visualcode but its public and its a website: https://codesandbox.io/

I know you fixed your question but next time you question try to add a code sandbox so we can help better anyways im glad you fixed your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pre tag preserves all text formatting such as white space and line breaks.
You can turn the word wrap back on in the pre tag css.

```
pre {
background-color: #CCC5B9;
border: 1px solid #999;
border-radius: 3px;
display: block;
width: 60%;
margin: 0 0 0 30px;
white-space: pre-wrap;
}

code{
color: #252422;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Consolas;
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer on that question for you

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-do-I-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag-in-HTML) web page explains how to wrap text in pre tag. In short, you should add something like this in yuor css:

```
pre
{
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
    white-space: -pre-wrap;
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Will whitespace: pre-wrap; be sufficient without adding the rest?

Comment: May be for your browser, it will. But I would keep the rest as well if you want this to be compatible with other browsers too.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Do you happen to know how I can adjust the position of the <code> text within the <pre> ?

Answer (score 0):

As it is code you should not allow extra word wrapping as that could affect what the code actually does, at least in some languages, and would not be correct if the user did some copy and pasting elsewhere.

A quick and simple way of making sure it always fits and maintains the correct line breaks is to set the font-size in terms of the viewport width.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
}

code {
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<pre>
            <code>
if (condition) { statement_1_runs_if_condition_is_true;
statement_2_runs_if_condition_is_true; } else {
statement_3_runs_if_condition_is_false;
statement_4_runs_if_condition_is_false; }
            </code>
</pre>
```

Of course, for this to work you need to know that your code will fit into the width with the given font size. This can be tested in advance and a suitable font-size chosen.

However, if you have a very dynamic situation where you are adding code say through JS during run time you will need the JS (can't be done in CSS unfortunately) to calculate the maximum line length (in characters) and adjust the font-size accordingly.

Comment: Great solution! however if I continue to minimize the browser some text will eventually be cut off with this method. Is there a way to counter this? I am not using JS, just plain html and css :)

Comment: Hi, why will some text eventually be cut off? Is it because some browsers don't let you put the font-size below a certain level (?I think that may be Chrome, not sure). If you haven't got room, you haven't got room, but in that case I think you'd want the code element to be wider than the device/viewport and allow scrolling (which is what SO does with its snippet code in questions for example) reather than show spurious newlines - depends on exactly your use case of course.